# React GraphQL Relay - How to do a simple query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, relaymodern

**The Goal:**

I'm trying to query a specific character from a [GraphQL server](https://github.com/neelance/graphql-go/tree/master/example/starwars) with relay.

**The Problem:**

The query works in GraphiQL. But here, when running `"relay-compiler": "^1.4.1"` I'm getting...

> ERROR: Parse error: Error: FindGraphQLTags: Operation names in graphql
>   tags must be prefixed with the module name and end in "Mutation",
>   "Query", or "Subscription". Got `clientQuery` in module `Jedi`. in
>   "components/Jedi.js"

**The Question:**

Can't I just query that specific character like in GraphiQL ? How can I achieve this?

**The Code:**

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { QueryRenderer, graphql } from 'react-relay'

const BlogPostPreview = props => {
 return (
   <div key={props.post.id}>{props.post.name}</div>
 )
}

export default QueryRenderer(BlogPostPreview, {
post: graphql`
         query clientQuery {
           character(id: 1000) {
             id
             name
             appearsIn
          }
        }
    `
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Operation names in graphql tags must be prefixed with the module name

You should rename your query (clientQuery) to BlogPostPreviewQuery if BlogPostPreview is the name of your module.

Answer (score 5):

Here are examples. If query is in:

- `/app/foo.js` - `fooQuery` or `fooAnythingQuery`
- `/app/foo/index.js` - `fooQuery` or `fooAnythingQuery`
- `/app/Foo/index.js` - `FooQuery` or `FooAnythingQuery`
- `/app/foo/bar.js` - `barQuery` or `barAnythingQuery`